# Page is always redirecting once?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, header

I coded a small CMS, which saves the user's ip and stuff at every page call. Because of this, I recognized, that seemingly my page always redirects the user once, because the page calls where logged into the database twice.

For debugging, I coded a function, which sends me a mail on every call with PHP's `$_SERVER`, `$_SESSION` and `$_REQUEST`.

Now after visting `http://example.com/contact` I get two mails:

One with:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://example.com/contact'
```

and one with:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://example.com/news'
```

although I never visited `/news` in this Session.

For pretty URLs I have the following .htaccess which redirects every request to index.php.

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

I searched my code for PHP header changes or other redirects, but could not  find any. Do you have any suggestions how to find out how and where this happens or do I have some errors in .htaccess?

The page is running on Apache2@Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Now it looks like it happens only in chrome, or at least it only happens sometimes?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

It was because of the **missing favicon**, which chrome tried to load by itself from a default path

plus

a **background image loaded by relative path with `"url:('...')"`** which also caused loading the whole page again because of the htaccess redirect